# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. oracle parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
var orclParam=new OracleParameter("p_amount",0);
```

I am getting this error,

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

So which one will be correct from bellow,

```
var orclParam=new OracleParameter("p_amount",0.ToString());
```

OR

```
var orclParam=new OracleParameter("p_amount","0");
```

Comment: Answer: var orclParam=new OracleParameter("p_amount",0.ToString()); or Answer: var orclParam=new OracleParameter("p_amount","0");

Comment: Above both are correct, instated of 0 we have to give "0"